# Redirecting to different customer account dashboards based on there customer groups

Tags: dashboard

We have 4 groups namely

1.customer 
2.Logistics 
3.service provider
4.printer

The task is to get different dashboards based on customer groups when they login to the Frontend.

So please guide me step by step for redirecting to different dashboards according to the customer group they belong.

I have tried creating a views for each dashboard and using `getcustomerId()` and passing if else statement between `Mage::getDesign()->setArea('dashboard')` and `Mage::getDesign()->setArea('dashboard1')` but nothing worked out.

Comment: Use a custom layout handle based on the customer group, as explained here:       http://www.atwix.com/magento/magento-customer-group-layout-handle/